# Is it safe to rename file encrypted using gpg public key?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

While using GPG for encryption is it safe to rename the file after it is encrypted or depending on the algorithm used for encryption the file uses the name also for verifying the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename the file without issues. The original filename is safely encrypted inside the file. The filename is never used for decryption in any way.